# Setting Background of Layout has white edges

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to make a popup DialogFragment and added a drawable with rounded corners as a background but probably since the window size of the popup is a bit bigger it shows white edges.

I will add that I also have a sign in Dialog popup which I was able to achieve the wanted result.
The Dialog class has the ability to use the following java code:

`dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

specifically the getWindow() function doesn't exist in DialogFragment

Is there an alternative to this for DialogFragments?

Here is my xml code of the constraint Layout with the background of the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/con_post"
    android:minWidth="350dp"
    android:minHeight="550dp"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="550dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context=".FragmentLogic.FragmentBlogPost"
    android:background="@drawable/sign_in_popup"
    android:padding="5dp">
```

[Fragment with white edges I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86SbU.png)

[Sign in for example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBdEM.png)

Thanks a lot in advance